# How to set a Like Button to an internal Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

is there a possibility to set an Like-Button at an internal Page? I've got a community where you have to be logged in to see pictures. I'd like to have a Like button at every picture, but if Facebook checks the link it'll redirected to a "Registration Page".

the workflow for a regular user is, that he can view 10 pictures and after that he has to register.

So, i used the iframe code for the button, but Facebook don't accept a click, because it is redirected to the register page.

Is there a solution for the problem?

Thanks
Regards
Carsten

Answer (score 1):

I created a local page inside my app to act as a pass-through, and include any values I need to properly load my internal page in the querystring:

```
http://www.myapp.com/FacebookPassThrough.aspx?Id=XXXXX
```

I used *that* for the LIKE button's data-href.

Then on the Page_Load event of the pass-through page I redirect to the Facebook permalink that loads my internal page:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/{YOUR COMPANY NAME}/{FACEBOOK ID}?sk=app_{YOUR APPLICATION ID}&app_data={YOUR URL ENCODED JSON OBJECT}
```

The app_data value is a JSON-ified object that gets parsed out on my Page_Load event (in my Master page), and I redirect as necessary from there.

I can provide the specific Facebook app URL if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably develop your own 'liking' system if you want to do this. Facebook intends Likes to be on globally visible pages - and what you're running into is an effect of that.

When the user clicks on the FB Like plugin, FB's robots attempt to scrape the page (or even better, read its OG meta tags). And since you're gating the page, the Likes will never have anything but the registration page as their OG data. The users may be successfully Liking different URLs, but they will all look like the registration page on their newsfeed stories, etc. - which isn't a really compelling ad for your app.

If you really want to gate content and have Likes on it, your workaround would be to not do a global redirect but to have a 'crippled' version of the page they are Liking that has the correct OG tags, image, etc. This would also allow the user's friends to come to something that had interesting content when they clicked on the newsfeed story, instead of a reg screen that they will promptly leave.